# Hard Merging in git

Tags: git, merge, branch

I want to merge a branch`A` with the `master` branch such that in case of any conflict branch `A` overrides the `master` branch.

Basically I want to replace the master branch by branch `A`

Any idea?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862590/how-to-replace-master-branch-in-git-entirely-from-another-branch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try a:

```
git checkout master
git merge -Xtheirs branchA
```

(as described in "[`git merge -s ours`, what about “`their`”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173919/git-merge-s-ours-what-about-their)":
This would avoid the `merge -ours` from `master` to `branchA`, followed by the merge from `branchA` to `master` described in "[How to replace master branch in git, entirely, from another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862590/how-to-replace-master-branch-in-git-entirely-from-another-branch)")

You also have various other options in "[git command for making one branch like another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911794/git-command-for-making-one-branch-like-another/4912267#4912267)"

As mentioned in "[Git: Merge to master while automatically choosing to overwrite master files with branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3364616/6309)", a reset would also be possible to completely *replace* `master` by `branchA`.