# Git repository url issues

Tags: git, bitbucket

I had repository with URL A - then i stopped working with it, and went to repository with URL B

Now i want to merge the changes from repository in URL B with the repository in URL A- in the process i need to wipe out everything that may have been in URL A, such that any files that were deleted in the process of making the project in URL B , will not be reincarnated...

How can I do that?

I am working with git and bitbucket

Comment: What does `i need to wipe out everything that may have been in URL A` actually mean? As an aside using A and B as in the question makes it hard to read, when compared to giving none-abstract names and/or showing the commands you've **tried** to use and their output. It's a lot easier to understand a question of the form `I did <this>, I got <that>, but I want <different> - how can I achieve <that>?`.

Comment: I agree to AD7six. My question: maybe what you want to do is not directly related to Bitbucket: how have you cloned your respository (command line interface, CLI)? You may want to show the CLI command (at least from your memory) that you used. Further: it sounds you'd like to either merge two working trees (not the history I guess) or maybe just rename the project? Try to use other periphrases as well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if RepoB was done from RepoA history (as a true fork: starting from RepoA, and changing everything in it), then importing RepoB history in RepoA coud be done (assuming the main history to merge is on the `master` branch) using "`ours`" [`git merge`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) merge strategy:

```
cd /path/toRepoA  # local clone
git remote add repoB /url/to/repoB
git fetch repoB
git checkout -b masterRepoB repoB/master
git merge -s ours master
```

That merge will make git consider `master` as merged to `repoB/master`... while keeping only `repoB/master` content (no files from `repoA/master` is in the result of that merge).

See also "[Why would one use “`git merge -s ours`”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5077688/6309)".

Then:

```
git checkout master
git merge masterRepoB
```

That will fast-forward HEAD from `master` to `masterRepoB`, making that `master` branch identical to `repoB/master` (`masterRepoB`)

You can then push `master` to /url/repoA: its content will be the one from repoB.